# ST3: New Build Systems / SideBarEnhancement: Keyboard shortcut that opens files to different browsers via localhost

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Using Sublime Text 3 on a mac. I'm currently learning d3.js and would like to be able to preview source codes on different browsers via the localhost, preferably, without using 3rd party browser plugins like Live Reload. It's not hardcore development so I don't really need to autoupdate to diff sized browsers.

What I'd like to do:

1. Able to open files via localhost `http://localhost:8888` NOT `file:///Users/USERNAME/Desktop/...`
2. Have the option to open files on different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) by just typing a shortcut

I was able to do the following:

- set-up a local server via terminal, `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &`
- bind a keyboard shortcut to SidebarEnhancement's Open in Browser
- Use this shortcut to open file onto the localhost ie., `http://localhost:8888/d3-book/chapter_04`
- tried making New Build Systems for each browsers, but I can't seem to get it to open onto the localhost. It instead opens to `file:///Users/USERNAME/Desktop/...`

Is it possible to get SideBarEnhancements to have the option for:

- Open in Chrome + keyshortcut
- Open in Firefox  + keyshortcut
- Open in Safari  + keyshortcut?

OR

Have Build Systems for each browser that opens to the localhost ie., `http://localhost:8888/d3-book/chapter_04`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer may using SideBarEnhancements "Open With" option as opposed to the "Open in Browser", which is going to load the system default (there may be an override, but I'm not aware of it).

You could look into an OS shortcut to switch default browsers as well.